# Не корректно работает мьют с ролью замьючен

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я паралельно разрабатываю 2 команды мьюта с тайм-аутом и обычный который представлен ниже. Основная проблема почему не корректно работает эта система потому что когда вводишь ">мьют @username 5час" то бот выводит и в канал и в лс того кого забанили пишет 300 часов а должно писать 5 часов то есть команда переводит часы в минуты то есть 5 * 60 = 300. На счет секунд и минут работает отлично. Но начиная с 1 часа и дальше оно считает в минутах. Прошу мне помочь так как не знаю как решить эту задачу

Правильное использование команды:

```
>мьют @username 5час
```

Вот код:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Мьют"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def мьют(ctx, member: disnake.Member, duration_str: str):
    role = disnake.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Замьючен(а)")
    if not role:
        role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Замьючен(а)")
        for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, disnake.TextChannel):
                await channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)

    if role in member.roles:
        embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"❌ **{member.display_name}** уже замьючен(а).", color=0xc80005)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        duration = parse_duration(duration_str)
        if duration is not None:
            await member.add_roles(role)
            time_unit = get_time_unit(duration)
            embed = disnake.Embed(description=f"✅ **{member.display_name}** получил(а) мьют на {duration} {time_unit}.", color=0xc80005)
            await member.send(f"Модератор {ctx.author.mention} замьютил Вас на сервере **{ctx.guild.name}** на {duration} {time_unit}.")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            await asyncio.sleep(duration * 60)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(description="❌ Неверный формат времени мьюта. Используйте форматы Xмин или Xчас.", color=0xc80005)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def parse_duration(duration_str: str) -> int:
    duration_match = re.match(r"(\d+)(мин|час)", duration_str)
    if duration_match:
        duration = int(duration_match.group(1))
        time_unit = duration_match.group(2)
        if time_unit == "мин":
            return duration
        elif time_unit == "час":
            return duration * 60
    return None

def get_time_unit(duration: int) -> str:
    if duration == 1:
        return "минуту" if duration < 5 else "минуты"
    elif 2 <= duration <= 4:
        return "минуты"
    elif duration >= 5 and duration < 60:
        return "минут"
    elif duration == 60:
        return "час"
    elif 61 <= duration <= 299:
        return "часа"
    else:
        return "часов"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]